# How to send parameter as Object from react js to Web API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, parameters, http-get

This is react js service call to get details from WEB Api,

***React js***

```
   var config = {};
    let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    this.config = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
    }

    > export function getQuote(quoteData) {
    > 
    >     var url = new URL(`${baseUrl}RCReservation/GetQuoteDetails`);
    >     Object.keys(quoteData).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, quoteData[key]));
    > 
    >     return fetch(url, this.config)
    >         .then(handleResponse)
    >         .catch(handleError); }
```

***WEB API***

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetQuoteDetails(QuoteRequest quoteRequest)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

that calling service comes to WEB api [GetQuoteDetails]. But the problem is parameters are showing null values. is there any solution for that.. please give solution anyone

Comment: also post what the request looks like as well as QuoteRequest model. Also you need to mention other details like method:"GET/POST etc"

Comment: i'm new learner to react js. don't have idea to pass request to web api, Could you please give steps to integrate with web api ...